# How to trap "Failed to load resource" error caused from ajax call using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.post("server.php", data)
  .done(function(data){
    //do something
  })
  .fail(function(xhr,status,error){
    //print the error
  });
```

I am sending some data to a webservice using Jquery post method, but if server.php is down or does not exist then this call fail but does not capture any error message. However in browser console i can see "Failed to load resource" error. Is there any way to trap this error message?

Answer (score 0):

You should use responsed data. For example:

```
     $.post("server.php", data)
      .done(function(data){
        $(".progress").hide();
        $("form").trigger('reset');
        $("#conferma").prop('disabled', false);
      })
      .fail(function(xhr,status,error){
        $(".progress").hide();
        $("#conferma").prop('disabled', false);
        alert("An AJAX error occured: " + status + "\nError: " + error);
      });
```

Comment: So i think error variable is undefined and status contains only "error" string.

Comment: No. According to specification, ajax errors can be `error`, `abort` or `timeout`.

Comment: Anyway. It's not possible to get this message from browser. You can defined your own error messages depending on the status.

Comment: Ok but "error" is not such a useful information. So how can i capture and alert the "failed to load resource" error, that the browser show me in console?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `.fail` callback, look at `status` and `error` variables.

`error` can have one on these values:
`"timeout", "error", "abort", "parsererror", null`

While `status` given the http status text, such as `Not Found` for 404 code, or `Internal Server Error` for the error text or error type

Comment: In my case, `error` seems undefined and `status` is equal to "error".